# Solve a tiny bug in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]
You can see in image at the right side, we have a small gap between border and div element. In left, it is OK, How to get rid of this thing.

```css
.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<section class="top-intro--section">
  <div class="intro container">
    <div class="row grey text--row">
      <p class="text--name">SNOOPY-DEX / STRIP GENERATOR</p>
      <p class="text--version">KME v1.3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row button--row">
      <button class="btn btn-generate grey">Generate All</button
            ><button class="btn btn-reset grey">Reset All</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about providing a [mcve]. The code you've provided does not demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Please pay attention to the tags you've selected (this includes actually reading their descriptions). Three out of five of the ones you've picked are not suitable for this question.

Comment: You need to complete the code so that it demonstrates the way your image shows.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can just set margin to 0.